# sphinx search enable ssl

Tags: magento-1.9, fulltext, sphinx

when I enable the SSL i got the following error and indexing search can any one now about this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was some some miss-configured SSL issue. Which i got fixed by configuring SSL chain certificate